# Evaluating $v$ for orbiting a golfball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

> *The curvature of Mars is such that its surface drops a vertical
>   distance of 2.0 meters for every 3600 meters tangent to the surface.
>   In addition, the gravitational acceleration near its surface is 0.4
>   times that near the surface of the Earth. What is the speed a golf
>   ball would need to orbit Mars near the surface, ignoring the effects
>   of air resistance?*

In the Gre question, it can be solved by using the equation $$x=x_0+V_{x_0}t +\frac12 a_x t^2$$ and $$y=y_0+V_{y_0}t +\frac12 a_y t^2$$

Where $a_y= -g \times .4$, $x=3600$, $y=2$.

But I want to solve it by the using of the equation of catelite planet.
Which is $$v= \sqrt{\frac{g R^2}{R+h}}.$$ 
Is it possible to do this in the above equation. I am saying this because h is not given in the question.

Comment: Isn't $h=0$ in your case. The ball is _on_ the ground.

Comment: but the ball have to be orbiting around the Mars. Do I have to use Centripetal force?

Comment: The equations you have work in Cartesian coordinates where gravity is always vertical. To do this correctly the direction of gravity must change to always point towards the center of the planet. Thus, you actually need equations in polar coordinates to get $v$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it in answer with diagram. Thogh I have done the solution in other simple way but I'm interested to know more technique. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates, with $r$ the distance from the planet center and $\theta$ the azimuth angle [the equations of motion](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/1302week3Polar08.pdf) (in coordinates along the radial and tangential direction) are

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -g \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \ddot{r}-r \dot{\theta}^2 \\ r \ddot{\theta} + 2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta} \end{pmatrix} $$

The situation you want is constant radius $r$, so $\dot{r}=\ddot{r}=0$ or

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -g \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-r \dot{\theta}^2 \\ r \ddot{\theta}  \end{pmatrix} $$

with solution $\ddot{\theta}=0$, $\dot{\theta}^2 = \frac{g}{r}$

The tangential speed is $$\boxed{v = r \dot{\theta} = \sqrt{g\,r}}$$ which is the solution you get in the catelite planet for $h=0$.